# Abnormal in simple rosbridge v2 / turtlesim example

Tags: rosbridge, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a good tutorial for rosbridge v1 quick start, at
https://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/wiki/Quick_start_rosbridge_and_ROS,
but I can't find a similar tutorial for rosbridge v2, so I tried to mimic turtlesim with rosbridge 2, based on the example file under rosjs, and here is the link of my html file
[link text](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5s01kllusu672y6/test.html)

During testing, I run the following commands in terminal,

```
roscore
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
rosrun rosbridge_server rosbridge.py
```

and then load the html file in Firefox.

Basically there are two issues observed,

1 when the 4 buttons are pressed, the turtle never move and rostopic echo /turtle1/command_velocity always give me

---

linear: 0.0
angular: 0.0

---

2 the subscription to topic "/turtle/pose" returns undefined and only returns once,

Received message on /turtle1/pose: undefined

Obviously I missed something in the above html file, so appreciate if anyone can give me some clue.

thanks
clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46900/abnormal-in-simple-rosbridge-v2-/-turtlesim-example/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not yet familiar with "ros_bundle.min.js".  However, I can answer this issue using "ros.js", found under "rosbridge_clients" in the release version of rosbridge_suite.  Using this ros.js, I used the following example page to control both turtlebots and AR.Drones:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14391589/tutorial/rosbridge_ardrone/drone_browser_teleop.html

In this case, the connection is created as follows:

var con = new Bridge("ws://localhost:9090");

Addressing point 1, publishing command velocity for moving forward is done as follows:

con.publish('/cmd_vel', {"linear":{"x":1.0,"y":0,"z":0},"angular":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}});

In Chrome, you should be able to inspect the actual websocket frame that is sent using the development tools (regardless of which ros.js you are using).  I found this description of inspecting websocket traffic useful:

http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/

I haven't tried subscribing to pose yet, so I will pass on speculating about the second issue.

---

Originally posted by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) with karma: 123 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0